# Why is my Docker swarm service replicated to only 3/5?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, scalability

I am new to Docker. When I create a service with `--replicas 5` I only got 3/5.

```
$ docker service create --name myservice -p 8080:8080 --replicas 5 service
```

```
$ docker service ls
lx0irwgtd9p2   myservice    replicated   3/5
```

Can anyone please explain why only 3/5?

Comment: so much missing diagnostics. Number of swarm nodes. any deployment constraints? what are the results of service ps. etc.

Comment: i have 3 manager node and 3 worker node, i found the probleme. the probleme is with my storage space, when i pull images to deploy it and scale it, i notice that my /var/lib is  saturate so it can not pull it. thank you for your reponse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, if Docker Swarm tells you than some of the replicas are created, but not all of them, it can mean 2 things:

- You added constraints to your deployment that are not satisfied. For example, if you add a constraint that says that you want 5 replicas, with 1 replica per worker maximum, you will only end up with 3/5 if you only have 3 workers.
- If you didn't explicitely add constraints, then it is likely that your workers are running out of disk space

Comment: Actually i fell in the second option, my workers were out of disk space. Thank you for your reponse.